# VBA: Getting coma separator instead of dot for decimal number selected from SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, vba, number-formatting

On the userform I have among others a price textbox (txtCena). The data from userform are saved in a SQL Server database. I can enter the price into textbox in "0,00" format (polish settings), but SQL Server stores decimal values in "0.00" format anyway.

I wanted to fill the price textbox with the latest price entered for chosen product from combobox list.

I've written an after update event which gets the price value from database but displays it with a dot instead of coma separator. There is also a simple change event for txtCena checking whether it is numeric, if not changes the background and label color for red.

I looked for solution, swiped 8 pages search engine here showed up, Googled as well but I didn't find one.

When I tried more obvious solutions like below in the price change event or after update product event, I've started receiving errors.

```
Me.txtCena = Format(txtCena, "0,00")
Me.txtCena = CDec(txtCena)
```

The txtCena is declared in userform_initialize event as Double.

I'd be very grateful for pointing what I am doing wrong as I'm going nuts.

It shouldn't be complicated, should it ?

Here's the code I am using to get the price from database:

```
On Error GoTo Cena_Initialize_Err:

rsCena.Open "SELECT MAX(Cena) AS Cena " & _
                "FROM [Produkt Usługa] AS P " & _
                "JOIN [Szczegóły transakcji] AS S " & _
                    "ON P.Prd_ID = S.Prd_ID " & _
                "WHERE P.[Produkt Usługa] ='" & Me.cboProdukt.Value & "';", _
                con, adOpenStatic

If rsCena.RecordCount = 0 Then
        rsCena.Close
        Set rsCena = Nothing
        Call txtCena_Change
    Else: rsCena.MoveFirst
            With Me.txtCena
                Do
                    .Value = rsCena.Fields("Cena")
                    rsCena.MoveNext
                Loop Until rsCena.EOF
            End With
End If
On Error GoTo 0

Cena_Initialize_Exit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsCena.Close
    Set rsCena = Nothing

Cena_Initialize_Err:
    MsgBox Err.Number & vbCrLf & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error!"
        rsCena.Close
        Set rsCena = Nothing
        con.Close
        Set con = Nothing
```

Comment: I am unable to follow what you are after. The separator you get is based on the environment settings. Since you are in the EU, the decimal separator is `,` instead of `.`. As long as the data is not dismantled, the display doe snot really matter.

Comment: The userform allows me to add data to SQL Server database. I can type the price into textbox  as decimal number with a `,` according EU settings `(0,00)`. While saving in database it's converted to US format `(0.00)` with a `.`.

When I want to use the value from the database and fill the textbox with the price, it is inserted into texbox with a `.` instead of `,`. I wanted to fill the price automatically so the user doesn't have to type in the price each time for the product, if it hasn't changed,

Comment: So could you not change the `MAX(Cena)` to `REPLACE(MAX(Cena), '.', ',') AS Cena`

Comment: Thank you, it works. I feel so ashamed... I wouldn't think of it. Will I ever stop drilling the issuses and seeing them over-complicated where there are so simple solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

As I found you have a `TextBox` binds to your DataBase, And this binding don't allow you to change `Text` of that `TextBox`, If I'm in a right way, I suggest you change your way to:

> Use a `Label` for showing your value in your custom format.

- For this way you can add that `Label` in front of your `TextBox`; or
- Hide your `TextBox` and show only `Label` and in `Click` event of `Label` show `TextBox` and hide `Label` and also in `Exit` event reverse that;

Comment: The textbox value is a parameter for a stored procedure which adds the data to database. The label just describes the textbox. But PaulFrancis solution works.

Comment: @kkris77 I prefer to use a `Label` for showing my custom formats instead of changing `TextBox` You will have your `TextBox` always without any change on sending its data anywhere ;).